# How to display large content quickly in browser

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Recently, I have a question about how does Google spreadsheet works ? It can display 10,000+ more rows within a few seconds after clicking the "Add Rows" Button.

Since every time I using the simplest method (like echo, document.write, print()...) of PHP or Javascript to display contents, it takes really a lot of time. Even I only want to print out few hundred of blank rows, it takes over 10 seconds.

Of course I am not expecting the same performance as Google. I just want to know if there are any other possible ways to reduce the time when displaying content in browsers.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I am trying on it.

Comment: Changing the HTML lots of times is slow. Create the HTML, or append to the DOM lots of times, the change the HTML once.